# mysql get the value of a column in a database as a percentage

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a database and am currently pulling data using the SELECT statement Where the information from the column Opinion equals either Negative or Positive.

what i want to also do is output the positive data as an overall percentage but Unsure if that would be possible i had a look at multiple overflow questions but couldn't see anything. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $sql = "select Opinion from survey where Opinion = 'Positive'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if (!$result) {
        die(mysqli_error($con)); 
    }

    echo "<div style='overflow: auto;'>";
    echo "<table width=40% border=1 align=center >
            <tr>
                <th>Opinion</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>"; 

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<tr align=center>';
            echo "<td>" . $row['Opinion'] . "</td>";    
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand your logic

Comment: I am sure I remember this question from a day or so back! Does not seem like you have changed your code since then.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to pull all the answers, to check into the `while` loop is the current answer is positive or not (and to count it ++) and at the end to divide this count to number all answers (available already into `mysqli_num_rows`)

Comment: To get a percentage you of course need to know how many questions were answered and how many questions were answered in the `positive` SO you will have to make 2 queries along the lines of `SELECT COUNT(id) from survey` and  `SELECT COUNT(id) from survey where Opinion = 'Positive'` Then  do a bit of simple mathmatics on those numbers

Comment: @RiggsFolly, is not needed to make two queries, only one with all the results would be enough.

Comment: @mitkosoft I was trying to keep it simple. the OP has been asking this question for some time now and making little or no effort to attempt anything for themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will calculate how many percentage of 'Positive' opinions compared to total rows of the 'survey' table:

```
select (SUM(IF(Opinion = 'Positive',1,0))/count(*))*100 as percentage_positive
from survey
```

The query below can determine the percentage of each different opinions at once:

```
select 
    Opinion,
    count(*) as total,
    (count(*) / (select count(*) from survey))*100 as percentage
from survey  
group by opinion
```

Comment: I've tried to echo the output but getting no output is this correct

 echo "<td>" . $row['Opinion'] . "</td>";

echo $count

Comment: try `echo "<td>" . $row['Opinion'] . "</td><td>" . $row['percentage'] . "</td>";`

Comment: have now fixed my issue Thankyou so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this as SQL query?

```
SELECT COUNT(Opinion) /  (SELECT COUNT(Opinion) FROM survey) * 100
FROM survey 
WHERE Opinion = 'Negative'
```

Answer (score 0):

After help from Kevin HR i have fixed my issue with the code below.

```
$sql = "select Opinion,count(*) as total,(count(*) / (select count(*) from survey))*100 as percentage from survey group by opinion";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   echo "<div style='overflow: auto;'>";
echo "<table width=40% border=1 align=center >
<tr>
<th>Opinion</th>
<th>Percentage</th>
</tr>"; 

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo '<tr align=center>';

                            echo "<td>" . $row['Opinion'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['percentage'] . "</td>";
         }
   } 
    else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code for getting the value of number of rows from a database

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `survey` WHERE Opinion='Positive'";

$connStatus = $con->query($sql);

$numberOfRows = mysqli_num_rows($connStatus);

echo "There are a total number of $numberOfRows Positive rows in the database";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
```